# What is the use of ISP and ICSP in Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, uploading

I am trying to connect gsm module with my arduino uno. confused about the use of isp and icsp

Comment: What GSM module are you using?  And what is the cause of the confusion?

Comment: i hav a module of sim900a and someone advised me to connect it to ard uno using isp or spi. now i m having queries like can we program using isp? why cant i use spi or i2c? how are they different? xcept i2c which uses uart, right?

Answer (score 6):

ISP/ICSP has no role when utilizing a typical, properly functioning Arduino, as the program code compiled from sketches is instead downloaded via a bootloader (either serial, often behind an on-board USB-serial converter, or else directly USB).

The role of ISP in the Arduino ecosystem is mostly limited to:

- Loading a bootloader into new chips which do not have one, or have somehow lost theirs (note however that you can buy pre-loaded ATmega328's from many sources at a small premium)
- As an alternative program loading scheme when the tiny amount of program memory used by the bootloader must be re-claimed for a particularly large sketch
- Programing alternate targets to which the Arduino libraries have been partially ported, especially resource-constrained ones where the bootloader takes up a larger fraction of the total memory, such as the the ATtiny25/45/85
- Replacing or modifying the firmware of an on-board USB-serial micro such as the 16u2 on an Uno to perform a different function, such as emulate a keyboard or mouse.  However, this chip can also be programmed over its USB interface in DFU mode.
- Programming other non-Arduino devices used in a project (though these often have a different ISP scheme than the ATmega series).

But a typical project using purchased board(s) will involve none of these.

---

SPI vs. ISP

As jfpoilpret points out, a very popular way of interfacing chips to a microcontroller is the Serial Peripheral Inteface, or SPI.  Like ISP, this is a synchronous (has a distinct clock line) serial interface with a master and a slave, a mode or enable pin, and a distinct data line in each direction.  Some Arduinos use MCUs like the ATmega328p which re-use their SPI pins for ISP (with the reset functioning as the mode pin).

In effect, ISP is a sort of special "SPI-like" interface mode for programming an ATmega - often using the master-mode SPI engine of the programer to do the actual transfers.  But "ISP" applies only when programming an ATmega - the more generic case of communicating with a peripheral would be "SPI".

It's my impression that most GSM modules use asynchronous serial interfaces (ie, utilizing a UART engine), but there may be some which use SPI or other synchronous schemes, at least as an option.

Comment: Don't you forget the thousands of devices using the ISP bus as the only way to communicate with them (just like I2C). That makes a common use for ISP in Arduino projects! Although I admit that you don't have to use the 2x3 header for it as you can find MOSI, MISO... on other pins as well, but you could.

Comment: @jfpoilpret - no, that is SPI, not ISP.  The ATmega328p happens to use the same pins for both, and they are indeed quite similar - we might consider ISP to almost be a special case of SPI.  But SPI is **not** a case of ISP.

Comment: Damn! How could I make this mistake? Of course you are right! Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: point 5 of roles, using that can i program at89c51 or other mcu?

Comment: That would depend on the scheme used by the MCU in question.  The at89c51 uses a parallel programming scheme, rather than a serial one.  You probably could build a programmer with an arduino, but would have to look into details such as if you would need an I/O multiplexer to drive all the lines, and if you need a transistor to enable a 12v programming supply, or if you have the version of the chip which programs at 5v.